# Does defaults() method exist in Password?

Tags: laravel

i made a service provider to validate the password in Laravel 8, but i get this error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password::defaults()
```

`PasswordRuleServiceProvider` was added in `app.php`

```
// Custom Service Providers
App\Providers\PasswordRuleServiceProvider::class,
```

This is the provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password;

class PasswordRuleServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        Password::defaults(function () {
            $rule = Password::min(8)->letters()->mixedCase()->numbers()->symbols()->uncompromised(3);
            return $rule;
        });
    }
}
```

I followed the Laravel doc to do this but it doesn't work, does the defaults method exist in Password? Thanks.

Comment: Why not check the source code? If that error message tells you that this class does not contain such a method, I would assume that this is the case

Comment: @NicoHaase yes, it exists: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Password.php#L107

Comment: Tried this on my local install, same error as you, but see the answer below, and check your version in `composer.lock`. For example: `"name": "laravel/framework", "version": "v8.40.0",`, so clear reason why it's an error for me, could be the same for you :)

Comment: @TimLewis yes, it's the v8.40.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the [commit history of that `Password` class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/f7e5b1c105dec980b3206c0b9bc7db735756b8d5), this method did not exist until Laravel v8.42.0 (released on May 18th 2021). Make sure that you are using at least that version if you want to call such a method.

---

Next time, you should check the source code in your project for such methods, and not any other version on the internet. The source code you've linked might be newer than that